# Uploading apk built on cordova gave error- 'Your apk signed with different certificate as pervious apk.'

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js, apk, keystore

The app wasn't built originally by me, so I don't understand keystore, alias and password. But I was given a key that kind of looks like this. I assumed it was one of the three.

> oi39.ElqNBBjc72BiKRprL9r4IpVKvtKxT-IioEpVlpW9FnoeKd8Do3jdoce93_komdho30cn_jd003j......Illsiiwk93si0s-D3g

Is it possible to update the app with this, and how would I approach it?

Comment: You APK should be signed with same keystore as your previous APK was signed, If you sign your APK with different Keystore then Google Play Store will not allow you to upload APK.

Comment: The above key (not the same. I changed it a bit) was given for uploading. If this is the case, how do I sign it?

Comment: you need Keystore file which has .jks extension and you will need alias name and password of keystore

Comment: Yes but is the content of the .keystore or jks file something like this